# Hölder type of inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, normal-distribution

Is the following inequality true? I can't find a counterexample so I start to believe it is true but I do not manage to prove it :) Any ideas?

Let $f$ be a **compactly supported bounded** twice continuously differentiable function with bounded derivatives, then
$$\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f''(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} e^{- \frac{z^2}{2s}}dz ds \leq C [f]_{\alpha}\leq C [f]_{\alpha} + C\|f\|_{\infty} = C \|f\|_{\alpha}$$
for some finite constant $C>0$ where
$$[f]_\alpha := \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$$and here
$$\|f\|_{\alpha} := [f]_{\alpha} + \|f\|_{\infty}$$
is the Hölder norm.

Observation: one can upperbound the integral by $C\|f'\|_{\infty}$ by a simple use of integration by parts. Using integration by parts twice is too much, the time integral explodes, so the question remains if there is a middle step in order to obtain the Hölder norm in the right hand side.

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused, do you mean $f''(z)$?

Comment: Yes sorry. Changed.

Comment: And what should the $\int_0^t$ at the start really be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $W$ be the standard Wiener process. Then,
by the Ito formula
$$
E[f(W_t) -f(0)] = E\left[\int_0^t f'(W_s)dW_s\right] + \frac12  E\left[\int_0^t f''(W_s)ds \right]\\ = \frac12\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f''(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} e^{- \frac{z^2}{2s}}dz\, ds,
$$
whence
$$
\left|\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f''(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} e^{- \frac{z^2}{2s}}dz\, ds\right| \le 2 E\big[|f(W_t)-f(0)|\big]\le 4||f||_\infty.
$$

So even the supremum norm alone is enough to bound the integral.

Comment: This is what I was in the process of typing out, except I think the top line should be $F(W_t)-F(0)$?

Comment: @Lost1, sorry, it should be $f(W_t) - f(0)$ (it is already).

Comment: Oh... Does this actually imply that one can upperbound $\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{(n)}(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\exp (-z^2/(2s) ) dzds$ for any $n$-th derivative using the argument above iteratively?

Comment: @Martingalo, no.

Comment: @Martingalo, but partially, yes. You can integrate $E[f^{(n-2)}(W_t)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{(n-2)}(\sqrt{t}x) \varphi(x) dx$ by parts many times. You will end up with an estimate like $|f^{(n-2)}(0)| + C(t) ||f||_\infty$. Unfortunately, $C(t)$ explodes as $t\to 0+$.

Comment: Take a function $g$ and assume $g'(0)=0$ Using your identities replacing $f=g'$, $f'=g''$ and $f''=g'''$ one gets $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} g'''(z) p(t,z)dz = E[g'(W_t)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g'(z) p(t,z)dz$ where $p$ is the Gaussian kernel and now one can bound it by $\|g\|_{\infty}$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Ah I see, you can upperbound any order but the constant $C(t)$ will eventually explode.. Is it then true that 2 times is the maximum times so that such constant $C(t)$ is integrable at 0?

Comment: @Martingalo, it does seem so.